"X Android SDK file not found: C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-35\android.jar."
I have installed android studio but i am always getting the following error that the android SDK not found and when i check in its path, i cant find the android.jar file.
I tried to start over the installation process but i still get the same problem and i tried to find where i can download the android.jar file separately to put it manually into the path folder: " C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-35\android.jar."

Please add more debugging information to your question! How did you try to install Android Studio? Do you use flutter? What is the complete error message? Did you check posts like flutter-does-not-find-android-sdk?
